# Optimum Utilization of thread pool in Kafka Consumption

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

I'm relatively new to Kafka and while trying consuming the messages, I've observed that,given a large number of producers and only 1 consumer with a multi-threaded pool(without factoring in consumer groups and partitions), when one thread finishes consumption it stays idle until all the threads are consumed.Can this be optimized to achieve highest utilization?

Comment: Which kafka client do you mean? java, C#, go?

Comment: Java -  Apache kafka

Comment: In don't think that kafka consumers are designed to be used like this. In my project we worked with confluent consultants who advised us from the beginning to use partitions and consumer groups. In fact our consumers consume one message at a time

Comment: But wouldn't that require multiple JVM's? The heavy lifting is done by some external process, so I am trying to look for solutions that would fit on a single JVM and still get maximum utilization out of the thread pool

Comment: Why multiple JVMs? you can have 4 java services e.g. that consume one topic in 4 partitions. Ideally your consumers should be isolated from each other and not be on the same machine